# Install Private Verdaccio Packages in Dockerfile

Tags: angular, docker, npm, build, verdaccio

I am building a Angular Application which needs some Private Packages from my Verdaccio Server.
My current solution with an .npmrc file in the Repo is not working.

Is there a another why to download the packages?

**.npmrc File**

```
strict-ssl=false
@mynpm:registry=https://verdaccio.private-registry.com/
@mynpm-backend:registry=https://verdaccio.private-registry.com/
//verdaccio.private-registry.com/:_authToken="PrivatToken"
```

**DockerFile**:

```
FROM node AS development

    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package.json ./
    
    RUN npm install 
    
    COPY . .
    
    RUN npm run build
```

My current problem is that the private packages can be loaded succesfull but packages like bson,yn from the public registry can't be found. It always tries to load the packages from the private registry.

Comment: could you provide examples? or what's the setup you have

Comment: @JuanPicado i updated the description with my example. The problem is that the public packages can't be found, he always trieds to load from the private registry. 
It seems that something is mssing